# MySQL Wildcards * and %

Tags: sql, mysql

What is the difference between `%` and `*` wildcards in MySQL?

In a query like so : `"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE MATCH (message) AGAINST('$string*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`*` can only be used as a wildcard (or truncation) in a full text search while `%` (match 0 or more characters) and `_` (match exactly one character) are only applicable in LIKE-queries.

Comment: @Alix Axel, yep - zero or more characters.

Comment: But `%` does **not** match NULL

Answer (score 6):

["An asterisk is the truncation operator. Unlike the other operators, it is appended to the word, or fragment, not prepended."](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304)

This only applies to `MATCH() ... AGAINST()` statements.

The `%` is a `LIKE` wildcard and has nothing to do with the `MATCH() ... AGAINST()`.

I hope that helps.