# PDO PHP If Username Exist, Increase Username By 1

Tags: php

I have this login and registration script from the net. Everything is working fine.

Objectives:
Usernames entered by the user will only be alphabets. If the username entered is not exist in the database, it will automatically add a number 1 on the username, example, user1.

Let's say the database have already had user1, user2, user3. Whenever a user entered user, it will then check what is the last incrementing number which in this case, it is 3, so it will then add into the database as user4.

Problems:
As I am trying to learn PDO as much as I could and it is still pretty difficult for me to understand. Also, I do not have any idea where should I start from.

Below are my current working code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){

        $errors[] = 'All fields are required.';

    }else if(!ctype_alpha($_POST['username'])){
        $errors[] = 'Please enter only alphabet letters.';
    }else{
        if ($users->user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'That username already exists';
        }
    }

    if(empty($errors) === true){

        $username   = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
        $password   = $_POST['password'];

        $users->register($username, $password);
        header('Location: register.php?success');
        exit();
    }
}

public function user_exists($username) {

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `userinfo` WHERE `username`= ?");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        try{

            $stmt->execute();
            $rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

            if($rows == 1){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function register($username, $password){

        $password   = sha1($password);

        $stmt   = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `userinfo` (`username`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?) ");

        $stmt->bindValue(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        try{
            $stmt->execute();

            // mail($email, 'Please activate your account', "Hello " . $username. ",\r\nThank you for registering with us. Please visit the link below so we can activate your account:\r\n\r\nhttp://www.example.com/activate.php?email=" . $email . "&email_code=" . $email_code . "\r\n\r\n-- Example team");
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

Is there any kind souls out there can help me out on this? Letting me know where should I start and what should I do? Or the flow of the whole procedure in achieving my objectives.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with PDO. For the algorithm itself, it's pretty easy and can be found in seconds if you search for *files* named this way. Just look for something like "php how to name files like windows new folder 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example how to change your function to check if the user exist .. and which is the last index.
It is not pretty but will do the job and may be point you to the right ideas.

```
public function register($username, $password){

        $password   = sha1($password);

    //check if the user exists and find first posible free index
    $_username = $username;
    if($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `userinfo` WHERE `username` = 'user' ")){
        $n = 1;
        $max_index = 20;
        while ($n < $max_index ) { //just to be safe
            $_username = $username . $n;
            if (!$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `userinfo` WHERE `username` = '" . $_username . "' ")) {
                break;
            }
            $n++;
        }
        if($n == $max_index){
            die("Sorry ,there already (".$max_index.") entries of this username.");
        }
    }
    //continue as normal just use $_username in the final query

    $stmt   = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `userinfo` (`username`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?) ");

    $stmt->bindValue(1, $_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    try{
        $stmt->execute();

        // mail($email, 'Please activate your account', "Hello " . $username. ",\r\nThank you for registering with us. Please visit the link below so we can activate your account:\r\n\r\nhttp://www.example.com/activate.php?email=" . $email . "&email_code=" . $email_code . "\r\n\r\n-- Example team");
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Do I still need to extract the latest number from the database, example user30, after I extract the 30 from the string, I replace the 20?

Comment: no, the `while` loop will stop for the first "free" userX,
so if you have users 1-29, $_username will become 'user30'.
20 is just limit .. how many times is reasonable to check, if you expect to get 30 repetition .. put this number a bit higher.

Comment: I am a bit confused. 20 is just the limit but let's say the database i have no idea how many userXX is there, so I will have to acquire the latest number and replace the limit right logically?

Comment: Nevermind, it's working! Although not very close but somehow manage to let me get there. Thanks! What I did was I extract the latest number that is in the database and using your function, I manage to get it working. Do I just edit my question to replace the working solution or do I click on Answer My Question?

Comment: putting query within a loop is bad. Imagine having 50,000 rows in table and running this script.

Comment: @iroegbu it is just example to point the OP what options are there, and if you review the code it is limited to a reasonable amount (20 queries max)

Comment: Hmm, since it is mentioned that putting a query within a loop is bad. I have updated my code which I am not sure if this is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add a Sql-Wildcard like % _ * [meaning see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070411/mysql-wildcards-and) to find all usernames they starts with "user" and have one or more charakter behind the "user"-string. Currently you only will get the username that excatly matchs the insert username. 
But you could get some trouble by using the wrong wildcard, then

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM userinfo LIKE username = user%;
```

will always selct usernames like user1, user2, user3 but also something like userhorst..

To the pdo, the pdo help you to protect you system from sql injections. The prepare function sends only something like a query with wildcars for your parameter, thats means they send your statement without the parameters, to the Database. After this you send with the bindValue-function the single values to the Database. And finally you will excecute the statement. During this process the datapase can check each sended value for invalid signs.

Finally you have to check your if-statement. You will only get true when one user with the same name was in the database in all other cases (0,2,3,4,5,6,7) you get false.. But you want

```
if countUsers equal 0 then: 
     return false; 
else 
     return true;
fi
```

Another part is you should thinking about using the `sha1`-hash, there are still better hashs to protect your passwords.

Comment: Meaning SELECT COUNT(id) FROM userinfo WHERE username= user%; will return user1, user2 and anything that have user in the string? So I need to change the statement to this : SELECT username FROM `userinfo` WHERE `username` LIKE :username ?

Comment: Yes this must normally fix your problem

Comment: Hi, although I didn't really get what you are trying to say but I have made it work. Thanks for the help too! =)

Comment: could you post the url to the page that you build?

Comment: This is the testing link : http://thefickleshop.com/dr3am3rz/lar/register.php

Right now am solving how to get the new username to display on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all usernames like `user*` using:

```
SELECT username FROM `userinfo` WHERE username LIKE 'user%'
```

Next you should sort your results using [asort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php):

```
asort($array_of_usernames);
```

then use [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) or [preg_match](http://www.php.net/preg_match) to get the number at the end of the username:

```
$number = substr($each_username, -1, 2) //within a foreach
```

Increment the number gotten then insert into database.

```
$new_username = "user" . $number++;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! It's working already but nevertheless I will still look at yours and see if there are ways to shorten my code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice putting query within a loop is bad iroegbu. I will try and see if I can change my current working code to your recommended flow. So I can follow the flow above you have provided?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering looking at your example, how do you get the last or the biggest number of that particular username?

Comment: use [substr](http://tr1.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) if you are sure of the string that comes before the number. Else you might need regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys!

Below are my current working code which I manage to tweak here and there based on the help given:

```
public function register($username, $password){

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username FROM `userinfo` WHERE `username` LIKE :username");
        $parse_username = "%".$username."%";
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $parse_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt ->execute();
        $user = $stmt->fetch();

        $n = 1;

        if($user){
            $db_username = $user["username"];

            $username_counter = preg_match("/".$username."(\d+)/", $db_username, $matches) ? (int)$matches[1] : NULL;

                while ($n < $username_counter ) { //just to be safe
                    $new_username = $username . $n;
                    if (!$user) {
                        break;
                    }
                    $n++;
                }
                if($n == $username_counter){
                    $n++;
                    $new_username = $username.$n;
                }
        }else if(!$user){
            $new_username = $username.$n;
        }

        $password   = sha1($password);

        $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `userinfo` (`username`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?) ");

        $query->bindValue(1, $new_username);
        $query->bindValue(2, $password);

        try{
            $query->execute();
            $_SESSION['new_username'] = $new_username;

            // mail($email, 'Please activate your account', "Hello " . $username. ",\r\nThank you for registering with us. Please visit the link below so we can activate your account:\r\n\r\nhttp://www.example.com/activate.php?email=" . $email . "&email_code=" . $email_code . "\r\n\r\n-- Example team");
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

I am not sure that my way of coding is the best or professional, it is just based on my little logical knowledge of the flow. If there are any area where I can improve or rewrite, help me out if you wish to. =)